# Retrieve data from an object

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
     var k = $('.tren li').filter(':not(:first):not(:last)');
        alert(k[0]);
    });
</script>
```

Live: http://jsfiddle.net/D9NTr/

It returns a message like `[OBJECT HTMLLI ELEMENT]`. How can I retrieve the value of the object?

Comment: Depends on what the object it is, please post the HTML part.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$(k[0]).text();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/niklasvh/D9NTr/2/

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the [text() method](http://api.jquery.com/text/) like:

```
alert(k[0].text());
```

I'll knock up a quick jsfiddle to demonstrate.

Answer (score 1):

Not applicable to your example. But if you need the html, then `k[0].html()`